# How quick the batch script need to be execute with same logic

Tags: windows, batch-file

Last some days i am stuck with my requirment.first i am explaining my logic.i am calculating the a specific line no of a file with some logic.then passing that to a  function :copy_text.in this function i am copying data.txt file to output file with adding one more line (line i passed as parameter) inside the file.my issue that the code is now working fine,but taking 7 minute to copy 40k records.if i will comment the function :line_count,it is taking just 30 secs to process but i can not able to add that line in my output file.

i can not change this enabledelayedexpansion and disabledelayedexpansion parameters because i am facing lots of issue at the time of printing values from file.because my file value contains ! and % characters,and also the length of my each line is more then 3000 chars.

Exp:**OtherInformation: 74.49% subsidiary of  Sources: tps://pro/search/xyz/card/index.html?code=!121212#!121;**

Only my problem is there in counting the lines of file to add the text in that particular line no.please suggest me how i will use this part to run the script quick.

```
@ECHO Off
echo.%time%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a hold_list_line_no=0 (This value will come from different logic)
::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
call :copy_text !hold_list_line_no!
endlocal
echo.%time%
pause
exit 0;

:copy_text
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set /a line=%~1
FOR /F "delims=" %%c IN (C:\Users\1519499\Desktop\data.txt) DO (
call :line_count
echo %%c>>output.txt
)

:line_count
SET /A i+=1
if %i% equ %line% ( 
type add_this.txt>>C:\Users\1519499\Desktop\output.txt 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO Off
echo %time%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a hold_list_line_no=0 (This value will come from different logic)
::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
call :copy_text !hold_list_line_no!
endlocal
echo %time%
pause
exit 0

:copy_text
set /a line=%~1, i=0
(FOR /F "delims=" %%c IN (C:\Users\1519499\Desktop\data.txt) DO (
   SET /A i+=1
   if !i! equ %line% type add_this.txt
   setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
   echo %%c
   endlocal
)) > output.txt
```

This method avoids the `call` command and `>>` append redirection, that are inherently slow... You may also empty the environment before the copy_text loop:

```
:copy_text
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims==" %%a in ('set') do set "%%a="
```

Comment: @Aacini-i tried as per your changes,but the counter is not incrementing so the add_this.txt is  not appending to output.txt file and getting message like "Maximum setlocal recursion level reached."

Comment: I suggest you to test this code _exactly as is written_, just insert a correct line number (and remove the comment enclosed in parens). When this code is combined with other one, you must insert an `exit /B` command at end of `copy_text` subroutine. I also suggest to insert the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line below `:copy_text` one. BTW there is no way that this code _alone_ caused the error message you indicate...

Comment: @Aacini-very good approch,now i reduced 80% of the time.But when i added the line for /F "delims==" %%a in ('set') do set "%%a="  after the :copy_text subroutine,the variables for path and file name (C:\Users\1519499\Desktop\data.txt)what i used in my main code came empty.now in my code i am not using that line.is there any issue for this.

Comment: In such a case, you may preserve the few used variables this way: `(` line `for /F "delims==" %%a in ('set') do set "%%a="` line `set "path=%path%"` line `set "filename=%filename%"` line `)`